# Dense subspace of $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Working on a larger problem relating to harmonic analysis I have come upon this measure theory issue. Suppose $\varphi$ is a measurable function on $U$ and $f \in L^p(U)$. $\varphi$ is not necessarily bounded, but consider the set $$\{ f \in L^p(U) \ : \ \varphi f \in L^p(U) \}.$$

How do I show this space is dense in $L^p$?

If we consider that $f \cdot \chi_{\{ \left| \varphi \right| \leq N\} } \to f$ in $L^p$ can this help us?

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes, appropriate edits have been madee

Comment: What is $U?$ What is the measure?

Comment: @zhw finite measure, bounded open set.

Comment: Bounded open set in what space?

Comment: @zhw in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Is it a finite measure on a bounded open subset of $\mathbb R^n,$ or is it Lebesgue measure on the same. Really, how are we supposed to know?

Comment: @zhw. Lebesgue measure, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @zhw. I don't think this alters too many things however.

Comment: Is $\phi$ integrable? You should add relevant facts like $U$ being bounded to the question rather than as a side note in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Your Idea of using $f\cdot \chi_{\{|\varphi|\leq N\}} \to f$ in $L^p$ is a good starting point.

We denote the set in question with
$$
 A= \{f\in L^p(U) : \varphi f \in L^p(U) \}.
$$

Then $g\cdot \chi_{\{|\varphi|\leq N\}}$ is in $A$ for all $g\in L^p(U)$.
Indeed:
$$
 \int |\varphi g\chi_{\{|\varphi|\leq N\}}|^p \mathrm dx
 \leq
 \int | N g\chi_{\{|\varphi|\leq N\}}|^p \mathrm dx
 \leq N^p \| g\|_{L^p(U)}.
$$

Now let $f\in L^p(U)$ be given arbitrarily.
Then $f\cdot \chi_{\{|\varphi|\leq N\}} \to f$
in the $L^p(U)$-norm. (This is because the measure of $\{\varphi>N\}$ goes to $0$ as $N\to \infty$).

Hence we can approximate $f$ with elements in $A$, so $A$ is dense in $L^p(U)$.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be because $\chi_{\{\lvert\phi\rvert\leqslant N\}}\rightarrow 1$ pointwise?

Comment: I dont think so. Pointwise does not imply convergence in $L^p$

Comment: Sure, but you have a dominating function, $f$, so the dominated convergence theorem applies. The measure of the set $\{\lvert\phi\rvert\leqslant N\}$ might be infinite for every $N$.

Comment: the measure cannot be infinite because OP stated that $U$ is bounded. But yes, dominated convergence theorem is a valid alternative. Also OP probably already knows that $f\chi_{\{|\varphi|\leq N\}}$ converges to $f$.

Comment: I see. Now I'm a bit confused. If OP already knows that $f\chi_{\{\lvert\phi\rvert\leqslant N\}} \in A$, and that $f\chi_{\{\lvert\phi\rvert\leqslant N\}}\rightarrow f$ in $L^p$, then what was the question?

Comment: The function $\phi$ is measurable, not necessarily integrable.

Comment: @copper.hat does this change anything?

Comment: @supinf: I just saw that the OP mentioned that the measure was finite in the comments, so disregard my last comment. (As an aside, the measure can be infinite even if $U$ is bounded, take the counting measure for example.)